# Application crashed when long click on first items

Tags: android

My Application is crashed when Long click on the First Items of the List view.Actually First Item is "Go To Up Folder" which is added manually and after "Go To Up Folder" List view items comes.Now i am using long click of all items of the list except "Go To Up Folder" items.
But when i Long click on "Go To Up Folder" my App is crashed.
A small part of my code is given below:

```
if (tt != null) 
{
if ((m_remotefilepath == null)|| (m_remotefilepath.matches("/"))) 
 {
 tt.setText(items[position].m_FileName);
 } 
else 
{
 if (position > 0) 
 {
 tt.setText(items[position].m_FileName);
} 
else 
{
tt.setText("Go To Up Folder");
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.up);
}
}
}
```

MY log cat:

```
04-27 12:06:21.635: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(230): Shutting down VM
04-27 12:06:21.645: WARN/dalvikvm(230): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-27 12:06:21.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at com.officelinq.android.OfficeLinQ.onCreateContextMenu(OfficeLinQ.java:1549)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.view.View.createContextMenu(View.java:4086)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ContextMenuBuilder.show(ContextMenuBuilder.java:81)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.showContextMenuForChild(PhoneWindow.java:1848)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:458)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:458)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:458)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:458)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:458)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:458)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:1703)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.widget.AbsListView.access$500(AbsListView.java:71)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:1656)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-27 12:06:21.965: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(230):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 12:06:22.235: INFO/Process(34): Sending signal. PID: 230 SIG: 3
04-27 12:06:22.285: INFO/dalvikvm(230): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-27 12:06:22.963: INFO/dalvikvm(230): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

The Code on line no 1549 is:
menu.setHeaderTitle(m_adapter.items[info.position].m_FileName);

Comment: Please, provide stack trace from logcat output if your app crashes.

Comment: You have `NullPointerException
` when creating context menu at `com.officelinq.android.OfficeLinQ.onCreateContextMenu(OfficeLinQ.java:1549)`. What is the exact that line of code?

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing a "long" click, it is trying to create a context menu, that was not set. Please set the context menu for the items and probably your problem will be solved.

Comment: public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
   ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
 {
  switch (m_tmpData.m_tempParamInt4)
  {
  case LIST_TYPE_FILEMANAGER: // List FileManager
   if (v.getId() == android.R.id.list) 
   {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    menu.setHeaderTitle(m_adapter.items[info.position].m_FileName);
    String[] menuItems = getResources()
    .getStringArray(R.array.menu);
    for (int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) 
    {
     menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
    }

   }
   break;

Comment: Please Suggest me how to set context menu for the items.

Comment: Probably the type of your *tt* or *items[i]* has a setContextMenu() or similar, please check the API.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem today too. It is caused by using SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL without calling ListView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(). Either use SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE or set a listener to make it disappear.